# changing gethours in javascript to 1-12

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to use the gethours() method in javascript but it keeps returning military time. can someone please help me out fixing it so that it displays clock time? (1-12). Thank you so much!

```
// Reroute from the conf.js script
var chat = $( '.chat-output' ),

    message = function ( message, userId ) {
        var dt = new Date(),
            time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes(); // + ":" + dt.getSeconds();

        return $( '<div class="chat-message color-' + users[userId] + '">' +
                    '<div class="chat-id color-' + users[userId] + '"></div>' +
                    '<div class="chat-user-message">' + message + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="chat-time">' + time + '</div>' +
                '</div>' );
    },

    addText = function ( text ) {
        // log.innerHTML += text;
        // log.scrollTop = log.scrollHeight;

        console.log( text );
    },

    addRemoteText = function ( userId, text ) {
        // addText( '[' + userId + ']: ' + text+'<br>' );

        chat.append( message( text, userId ) );
        chat.scrollTop( chat.get( 0 ).scrollHeight );
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ampm(date){
    var dt= date || new Date, 
    h= dt.getHours(), 
    m= dt.getMinutes(), 
    s= dt.getSeconds(), 
    ampm;

    if(h>12){
        h-= 12;
        ampm= (h%12)? ' PM': ' AM';
    }
    else ampm= (h%12)? ' AM': ' PM';

    m= m<10? '0'+m: m;
    s= s<10? '0'+s: s;
    return [h, m, s].join(':')+ampm;
}
```

**ampm()**

```
/*  returned value: (String)
11:52:55 PM
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var dt = new Date();
var hours = dt.getHours();
var ampm = hours > 11 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
if (hours > 12) {
    hours -= 12;
} else if (hours === 0) {
    hours = 12;
}
var time = hours + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ' ' + ampm;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrsFV/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version of formatting a time in 12 hour format:

```
// Returns formatted time for given Date object, or
// current system time if d is falsey.
function getTime(d) {
  d = d || new Date();
  var hrs = d.getHours();
  var pad = function(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+ +n};
  return pad(hrs%12 || 12) + ':' + pad(d.getMinutes()) + ' ' + (hrs<12? 'AM':'PM');
}

console.log(getTime(new Date(2014,2,24, 0, 5))); // 12:05 AM
console.log(getTime(new Date(2014,2,24,10,25))); // 10:25 AM
console.log(getTime(new Date(2014,2,24,20,15))); // 08:15 PM
```

Note that 24hr time is preferred in many cases to avoid anomalies like 12:00 AM (which is really neither AM or PM) and 12:00 AM being before 01:00 AM.